# Three.js - how can i use fixed background image as environment map for 3d model

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader

i was looking at some models on sketchfab and i found many models have texture that are from background.

I know how to use cubecamera and render target to simulate refraction and transparency in three.js but how can i achive this look with fixed background that is not moving like a cube.

example:
https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/diamond-4c31bb47a726423c8db8ecc9c5cd35dc

see how fixed background is applied on that object as you move it around like transparency.

Can you do this without shader or you have the use one and how?
Thanks.

Comment: `scene.background` can be set as a color, a texture and a cube texture.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two different textures: Assign a material's [envmap](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshStandardMaterial.envMap) for the reflections or refractions, and assign a flat texture for the static [scene background](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/scenes/Scene.background).

```
var textureCube = // ... however you're creating your CubeTexture
diamondMaterial.envMap = textureCube;

var bgTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('url/path/img.jpg');
scene.background = bgTexture;
```